# Is it bad practice or is there a cost in marking a function, typescript interface, or typescript type with export, and then never import it?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, export

This seems to me like a simple question but I cannot find anyone else who has asked this question before.
I am working on a TypeScript project with Vue and a developer has marked a bunch of interfaces and methods with export but has not used them anywhere else in the application. For example 
`export interface CustomStageEvent`.

What is the cost to marking something with export? Should I care if something is exported and not used anywhere else?

Thanks

Comment: It's not reasonable to mix them. Functions and other JS objects exist at runtime and can increase footprint on import if they weren't tree-shaken. Types can't, the only risk is that IDE intellisense will be polluted with things you never use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cost of *any* API that is made public (which is what this does), is that you can no longer change or remove it, because someone, somewhere, may be using it, and you would break their code.

As an extreme example just look at *how long* it took to remove `sun.misc.Unsafe` from Java, and *how much* code was broken by that removal *even though the documentation explicitly stated that you are not allowed to use it*. (In fact, `sun.misc.Unsafe` is actually still there, so the removal actually *failed* because so much code uses it, even though it is explicitly forbidden to do so.)

If you export an API, you are making a promise to the users of that API. Only export APIs for which you are prepared to make and uphold that promise.

Comment: So your saying only export it if it is needed elsewhere otherwise you cannot make changes to it in the future because something somewhere could be using and it could break it? Seems fair.

Comment: If you export an API, you are making a promise to the users of that API. Only export APIs for which are prepared to make and uphold that promise.

Comment: My question is not necessarily related to an API however, this is more for internal export and import statement within an applications source code.

Comment: Being an internal API does not fundamentally change the problem, only makes the scope smaller. If you make a change to an internal API, instead of potentially breaking the code of every programmer on the planet, you only potentially break the code of every programmer in the organization. It is much easier to warn about and coordinate such changes within an organization than in the entire world.

Answer (score 1):

Besides @Jorg W Mittag's great answer, if you're thinking about performance, I don't think it has any noticeable impact.

Your module will still get parsed by JS runtime even if you mark something as exported or not.

Probably your memory footprint is gonna be the same, as the module will keep references to internal methods anyway. I'm not sure if you'll get a smaller memory footprint if you have internal methods that are not referenced from within the module, as they could be safely removed.